# How to loop inside a method Vuejs 2?

Tags: laravel, loops, vuejs2

I have a problem looping into a vuejs method.
I would like to loop over the elements into the cart to pass it with an axios call into the controller.

[image]

The thing is that it seems that the loop is not allowed inside the method:

**The Restaurant.vue**

```
        submitNewOrder() {
        let order_client = {
            user_id: this.restaurant.id,
            name: this.client.name,
            lastname: this.client.surname,
            address: this.client.address,
            phone: this.client.phone,
            email: this.client.email,
            total: this.total,
        };

        //do a loop of the cart to fetch all the dishes

        let order_dishes = {
            dishes: this.cart,
            foreach(dish in dishes){
                dish.restaurant_id = this.restaurant.id;
                dish.user_id = this.restaurant.id;
                dish.quantity = dish.quantity;
                dish.price = dish.price;
                dish.subtotal = dish.price * dish.quantity;
            }
        };

        axios
            .post("/api/orders/store", order_client)
            .post("/api/orders/store", order_dishes)
            .then((response) => {
                this.removeAllFromSession();
                this.hideCheckout();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

**OrderController**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //validate data and fill
    $validatedOrderData = $request->validate([
        'user_id' => 'required|exists:users,id',
        'name' => 'required|max:50',
        'lastname' => 'required|max:50',
        'address' => 'required|max:100',
        'phone' => 'required|max:15',
        'email' => 'required|max:50',
        'total' => 'required|numeric',
    ]);

    $validatedOrderDishesData = $request->validate([
        'order_id' => 'required|exists:orders,id',
        'dish_id' => 'required|exists:dishes,id',
        'quantity' => 'required|numeric',
        'subtotal' => 'required|numeric',
    ]);


    $newOrder = new Order();
    $newOrder->fill($validatedOrderData);
    $newOrder->dishes()->attach($validatedOrderDishesData['dishes']);
    $newOrder->save();


}
```

Comment: Most probably:  `order_dishes` might be the culprit you are talking about, But it seems to be an object to me. You are trying a `foreach` inside an object.

Comment: Yes, u're right, but how can I do a loop and send the data in the controller otherwise? @SachinBahukhandi

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see this line seems to be the culprit:

```
let order_dishes = {
        dishes: this.cart,
        
    };
```

Removing the `foreach` from the object and keeping it outside the object, should do the trick.

```
        //let order_dishes = {
          //  dishes: this.cart,
        //};
        let dishes= this.cart;
        foreach(dish in dishes){
            dish.restaurant_id = this.restaurant.id;
            dish.user_id = this.restaurant.id;
            dish.quantity = dish.quantity;
            dish.price = dish.price;
            dish.subtotal = dish.price * dish.quantity;
        }
```

Now you can replace  `.post("/api/orders/store", order_dishes)` with  `.post("/api/orders/store", dishes)`